# Accessing model in middleware in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a multi tenant app and I am distinguishing the tenant based on the subdomain.
I have registered a global middleware on the laravel kernel and I need to use my model in the middleware to get DB connection and then assign the values to a second mysql connection.

I tried doing what the documentation said but being a bit on laravel I am not getting my head around this.

Below is my middleware.
Seems like a linking issue.

This is my middleware.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TenantIdentification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        $router->model('tenant', '\App\Models\Tenant');
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $tk = "HYD"; //hardcoded for the time being

        $tenant = \App\Models\Tenant::where('tenantKey', $tk)->first();

        var_dump($tenant);
        exit();
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Below is my model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tenant extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tenantinfo';

}
```

I get

> "FatalErrorException in TenantIdentification.php line 28: Class
>   'Class 'App\Models\Tenant' not found".

Line 28 is `$tenant = \App\Models\Tenant::where('tenantKey', $tk)->first();`

My model is located in app\Models\Tenant.php
Does the boot function do anything? If I can load the model there, how would I refer to it within the handle method?

Comment: Is the name of class in the file app\Models\Tenant.php correct? Please show us content of this file

Comment: It is mentioned above. The model named "Tenant".

Comment: Sorry. Change your namespace in the model to App\Models;

Comment: hah felt it was something small like that. It's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model file you were invoking the namespace with **just** `App` and you referenced it with `App\Models`.

Therefore, change the namespace in the model file to

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Answer (score 1):

in the model file how about replacing

```
namespace App;
```

with

```
namespace App\Models;
```